# ruby on rails: Why does the model data appear in the browser?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'd like to create a simple blog without the scaffold generator. I generated the controller and manually created the views.

First I define the `create` action( including def new) in the controller and then I proceeded to make the views. After that, I create a model called `article` and added fields like title and body. The show views are alright but when I created the index page and looped through all the articles, the model data are also shown.

First article <3 Second Article

> [#Article id: 1, title: "First article <3", body: "This is the body of
>   the first article and i create...", by: "Ahmad Aziz", created_at:
>   "2015-03-30 11:50:03", updated_at: "2015-03-30 11:56:37">, #Article
>   id: 2, title: "Second Article", body: "This is the second article",
>   by: "Ahmad Aziz", created_at: "2015-03-30 11:53:31", updated_at:
>   "2015-03-30 11:57:13">]

How can i remove the model data from the index page? thank you.. I am sorry if my explanation is bad. I don't really know what this thing is called.

I'm using `rails 4.2`.

Comment: Please, provide code of your problematic template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to loop through your model and call the fields that you want on to display on the page...ie:

**index.html**

```
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
  <h1> <%= article.title %> </h1>
  <p> <%= article.body %> </p>
<% end %>
```

If you just print the article itself, you're going to get the who object

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you aren't doing something like

```
<%= @articles.... %>
```

Somewhere.

That "=" right there would print the object.